# Why does git return permission denied (publickey)?

Tags: git, ssh

I have a project on the server and git remote repository. Server and repository has ssh-pair (if I am on the server, I can clone any project from remote git repository via ssh). I want to clone the project from the repository to the my local machine, so I copy via scm `.ssh/` folder from the server and put it in my `/home/` folder.

However when I try clone project from repo to my local machine, git returns an error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate an ssh key for git to recognize your device as permissible in `~/.ssh`.

visit https://github.com/settings/ssh to ensure you have an SSH key associated with your device.

If you do not, you can generate a public key following the instructions here:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

afterwards, add the key to your git account and you should be able to run `ssh -T git@github.com` to confirm successful connection.

Comment: thank you, but I do not have access to the repository and therefore I can not add my key.I must use only this key

Comment: i'm not sure i understand - in this context, the key is associated with your github account, not a repository. log in to github, then configure your ssh settings with the instructions above. 

if the account does not belong to you and repo is private, the account owner will need to authorize your access by adding your username to the repository in question https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/

Comment: what happens when you run `ssh -T git@github.com` ?

Comment: I know this, but the repository it is not github.I try to explain it again: I am not owner of the repository, but I have access to the server which is can clone a repository via ssh.Then, I copy `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` to the my `.ssh/` folder and try get access to repository from my local machine

Comment: I see - so try this ensure your public key is added to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote server (see answer below by joran) - then, on your local machine, in project directory, specify the remote repository `git remote add origin git@MY_SEVER:MY_USERNAME/MY_PROJECT.git` - perhaps you will find this resource useful https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps

Answer (score 1):

You should add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

**EDIT**
If you have copied the ssh keys to your local machine you may also need to add them to your local ssh-agent `ssh-add <key file>`, you can check what keys has been added to the agent by running `ssh-add -L`.

Comment: where does the server?I want a clone project from repository to my local machine using only ssh keys from server